# rjags does not seem to use initial values specified

Tags: r, jags

I'm running the following normal / poisson simulation, and fitting the model with rjags. I'm having trouble getting rjags to actually use the initial values I specify. In this simulation, I am specifying that theta[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMTkv.png) should start with an initial value of 150, however, you can see clearly from the trace plot that it is starting at a value near 0.

Any suggestions?

```
set.seed(101)
library(data.table)
service <- data.table(id=1:1000,sjobs=c(rpois(250,0.1),rpois(250,0.15),rpois(250,0.25),rpois(250,0.25)),system=rep(1:4,each=250))
cost <- data.table(id=rep(service$id,times=service$sjobs))
setkey(service,id)
setkey(cost,id)
cost[service,system:=system]

cost.sim2 <- function(x){
  if(x==1)
    return(rnorm(1,150,10))
  else if(x==2)
    return(rnorm(1,150,10))
  else if (x==3)
    return(rnorm(1,150,10))
  else if (x==4)
    return(rnorm(1,150,10))
}


cost[,cost:=sapply(system,cost.sim2)]
service[cost[,.(sumcost=sum(cost)),by=id],sum.cost:=sumcost]
service[is.na(sum.cost),sum.cost:=0.0] 

library(rjags)

model.strings <- list(model1="
model {
  for (i in 1:N){

    y[i] ~ dnorm(eta[i]*theta[system[i]], 0.01/(eta[i]+0.000001))
    eta[i] ~ dpois(lambda[system[i]])

  }

  for(z in 1:4){
    theta[z] ~ dnorm(50,0.00000001)
  }
}")[![enter image description here][1]][1]
model.spec <- textConnection(model.strings$model1)

jags.inits <- list(eta=rep(10,1000),theta=c(150,150,150,150))
jags <- jags.model(model.spec,
                   data = list(#'eta' = service$sjobs,
                                'lambda'=c(0.1,0.15,0.25,0.25),
                               'y' = service$sum.cost,
                               'system' = service$system,
                               'N' = nrow(service)),
                   inits=jags.inits,
                   n.chains = 1,
                   n.adapt = 0)


js.coda <- coda.samples(jags,c('theta','eta'),n.iter=100)
plot(js.coda[[1]][,c('eta[5]','theta[1]')])
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

rjags uses inital value. Your theta merely have fallen from 150 to about 5 for only one iteration (from 0 to 1). The main causes are the model and eta's inital value.

```
model.strings <- ...
model.spec <- ...
jags.inits <- ...
jags <- ...

jags$state()[[1]]$theta       # model$state() returns the present values
    # [1] 150 150 150 150     # iter=0's theta

js.coda <- coda.samples(jags,c('eta','theta'), n.iter=1)
jags$state()[[1]]$theta       # iter=1's theta
    # [1] 3.608781 4.668491 7.904416 6.406210
js.coda[[1]][,c("theta[1]","theta[2]","theta[3]","theta[4]")]
    # theta[1] theta[2] theta[3] theta[4]
    # 3.608781 4.668491 7.904416 6.406210    # the same
```

Comment: If we were to not specify `n.adapt` (thus letting it default to 1000), would the `jags.inits` get ignored (though specified)?